# Getting error with sun.net.ftp.FtpClient by using JDK 1.7

Tags: ftp, java-7, ftp-client, sun

I have developed a project that uses `sun.net.ftp.FtpClient` class to download a file from an ftp server whil i was using JDK 1.5. 
Now i have switched to JDK 1.7 and i get the following error.

```
java: sun.net.ftp.FtpClient is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

It seams to me JDK 1.7 does not support **FtpClient** .

Any suggestions to solve this issue are welcome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use classes in `sun.*` - there are no guarantee that they will remain compatible between java-versions.

I would suggest a rewrite to use something like [Apache Commons FTP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) instead. It should be pretty simple to use, so it should be an easy job.

Answer (score 3):

Even though there is truth in that classes in `sun.*` should be avoided, the answer does not address the error appropriately, besides suggesting an alternative.

I don't have a scope on the context in which you are trying to instantiate `sun.net.ftp.FtpClient` - but it is still possible to do so.

The class is abstract, so you can't instantiate it. (See [§8.1.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1))

All is not lost though.
To get an instance of `FtpClient`, you can use the static methods from `sun.net.ftp.FtpClientProvider` that is found in the SDK to do so, like in the example below:

```
...
final FtpClient ftpClient = FtpClientProvider.provider().createFtpClient();
final InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ftpUrl.getHost());
final int port = ftpUrl.getPort();
final InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(inetAddress, port);
ftpClient.connect(socketAddress);
ftpClient.login(username, password.toCharArray());
...
```

There is a bit more work involved, but it allows you to avoid adding a new library with heaps of classes that you don't need - it depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

There are some changes since 1.7.
Such as:

```
 * before 1.7
 * FtpClient fc=new FtpClient(url,port);
 * fc.login(user, pwd);
 *  fc.binary();
 *  fc.put(remotefilename);
 *  fc.closeServer();
 *  
 * since 1.7
 * FtpClient fc = FtpClient.create(url)
 * fc.login(user, null, pwd);
 * fc.setBinaryType();
 * fc.put(remotefilename,true);
 * fc.close();
```